# Bootstrap carousel not moving

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an WP custom theme based on Bootstrap framework and I have added following carousel:

```
<div class="container slideshow">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-454586">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
            <img alt="slider" src="http://localhost/vyskoveprace/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/2_640_250.jpg">
            <div class="mask"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption col-md-6">
                <h2>Header1</h2>
                <p>Some Text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="item">
            <img alt="slider" src="http://localhost/vyskoveprace/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/1_640_250.jpg">
            <div class="mask"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption col-md-6">
                <h2>Header2</h2>
                <p>Some text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I use following code to initialize it, but it doesn't seem working. Could anybody help me out of this situation? No error produced. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<script>
(function($) {$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel-454586l').carousel({
    interval: 4000,
  });
});})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no error? You checked your browser console? I forget to all the time. Also, did you typo the ID? In your HTML it's `carousel-454586`, while in your Javascript it's `carousel-4545861` -- note the extra `1`. If setting the IDs to match fixes it, lemme know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Huh... That was the problem! Thanks a lot! Can I delete my so-late-night post somewhere here?

Comment: If you want to, there's a link just under your tags, just above the comments, labeled 'delete'. I'm not sure this is delete-worthy, though. Could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a slight typo in your `id` attributes -- in your Javascript, you're telling it to look for an element with id `carousel-454586l`, but your HTML only defines one with the id `carousel-454586`. Change either to the other and it will work. For example, change your Javascript to:

```
<script>
(function($) {$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel-454586').carousel({
    interval: 4000,
  });
});})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Note the ***bold/italic*** part -- that's where the difference is.